# Is there a way to notice the skin class of a Spark Button that his width have been modified?

Tags: flex4, components, flash-builder, flex-spark

I am resizing externally a spark button component, but inside if i have a Rect object and some Path it can be resize by setting them to 100% width.

But in case of many path or with a simple swf asset, is not working anymore.

The width can be setted correctly at first time you show the component. But after, i am not able to change it.

I am looking for a method or a handler inside the Spark architecture which can received the change inside the skin class, so i could adjust all the Visual Elements inside my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the updateDisplayList Method, it should be good

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                trace("unscaledWidth"+unscaledWidth);
            }
```